# The meaning of 気もない

Tags: meaning

I was intrigued by the meaning of **気もない**, and so far I could only find one reference from **Romajidesu.com**.

It described **気もない** as: 1. **showing no signs of**; **there being no hint of**, 2. **unthinkable**.

I was just wondering if there are only that many meanings for **気もない**, or if it could also be translated as: **don't** (**won't**) **even mind/care**, etc.

As far as I have learnt, **気** itself has quite many meanings, so I was confused that **Romajidesu.com** only stated so few for it.

Thank you in advance for your kind guidance.

Answer (score 1):

[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/気もない/](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%B0%97%E3%82%82%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84/) says

1. showing no signs of
2. insignificant
3. unthinkable

It seems to mostly match RomajiDesu

[https://www.weblio.jp/content/気も無い](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E6%B0%97%E3%82%82%E7%84%A1%E3%81%84) says

1. showing no signs of
2. unthinkable

The definition from [https://kotobank.jp/word/気もない-487978](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%B0%97%E3%82%82%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-487978) is word for word, the exact same as goo.ne.

[https://www.linguee.com/japanese-english/translation/気もない.html](https://www.linguee.com/japanese-english/translation/%E6%B0%97%E3%82%82%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84.html) says (copy pasted text below):

気もない
there being no hint of ~~
less common:
showing no signs of ~~ ·  unthinkable
なもない
insignificant

Similar to goo.ne and RD

---

It seems that there really aren’t many definitions for 気もない, and RomajiDesu was mostly accurate.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts in searching so many references. I was thinking that maybe native speaker knows some other meaning than those.

Comment: This question is complicated by the existence of the する気はない construction, which can be reproduced as する気もない. See here: https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e6%b0%97%e3%81%af%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84 and here: https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e6%b0%97%e3%82%82%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84
Edit: Though I know of no meanings that have much to do with caring/minding.

Answer (score 0):

This question might have attracted the kind of answer you were looking for earlier if only you had asked about either 気がある or 気がない.

When it’s used by itself (i.e. without being preceded by a verb), 気がある means the subject is romantically interested in someone.

> 彼は彼女に気がある。
> He has a *thing* for her.

気がない is the negative of that. 気もない would add the sense of “not even” to it, but I cannot think of a realistic situation where this would sound natural.